# Strange code throwing compile error template< J, int aSize=10> C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on an interesting problem.

Customer has code that builds in VS2013, they had a proliferation of macros, and in one case I couldn't understand why.  Visual Studio 2013 Platform toolset V120xp.

```
template< class J, int a_iSize = 10 >
struct testme {
private:
    vector< J > data;
};
```

The above code throws the error:

> 1>c:\customers\xxx.h(334): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

However, if they change all of their USES of the struct `testme` by wrapping it with a macro as in:

```cpp
#define TEST_ME testme
```

The code compiles fine.

I'm a newbie to templates and wonder if there is something base level that I'm missing.

I generally understand the concept of templates, but this is an interesting nuance.

I need to dig down and create a smaller test case.  At the moment, the above code snippet is part of a larger block of code, so there could be something in the call that is causing this.

Also, I could run the 'C' preprocesor only and compare the two `*.i` files.   This may show up something.

The customer wrapping the use cases of the template function with a macro is interesting. When I see this, I think "There is something missing, that if done, could eliminate the use of a macro."  That's the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: What is `vector`?  If you mean `std::vector` then you should have `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes Exactly.  Thanks for the response and for the opinion on "meaning what you say".  As I said this is customer code.  I am running McCabe metrics on complexity and trying to clean it up, just so I can assist in maintaining/developing.  As the naked "vector" had built before, I had assumed it was something specific to the template syntax, as that is something I don't use much (yet).

Answer (score 2):

For this code:

```
template< class J, int a_iSize = 10 >
struct testme {
private:
    vector< J > data;
};

int main()
{
    testme<int> t;
}
```

The following error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<
```

is duplicated [here](https://godbolt.org/z/kXvB6o).

What is probably occurring is the lack of specifying that `vector` is in the `std` namespace.

This is why header files should use the namespace name, and not rely on some outside file to provide this name.

In addition, the `<vector>` header should be included in the file.

```
#include <vector> 
template< class J, int a_iSize = 10 >
struct testme {
private:
    std::vector< J > data;
};

int main()
{
    testme<int> t;
}
```

The following compiles with [no errors](https://godbolt.org/z/9Z-NdW).

Comment: Thanks Paul, I eventually came to the same conclusion, this link  lead me to the same conclusion.  I need to understand what changed as this code has been in use. Likely a using std; was clipped somewhere.  So actually it wasnt really a template issue at all. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2143?view=vs-2019

Comment: Maybe there is an `#ifdef` that gets turned on/off depending on some compiler defined constant (like the compiler version number).